# Wix preprocessor variable value includes quotes

Tags: wix, wix3.11

using Wix 3.11, project built using msbuild 14.0.25420.1

I've come across a situation where a string I define in a proprocessor variable is having the enclosing quotes included within the variable value.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me:

1. why this behaviour occurs ( am I doing something wrong ? )
2. how I would quote a string value with spaces

The project has a main *.wxs* file, plus a number of *.wxi* *Include* files.

In the main *Product.wxs* within the *Wix* element:

```
<?define registry_key_path="SOFTWARE\MySoftwareGroup\MySoftware" ?>
```

Then in an include file *Component.wxi* within a *Component* element:

```
<RegistryValue
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="$(var.registry_key_path)"
  Name="InstallFolder"
  Value="[INSTALLDIR]"
  Type="string" />
```

The install fails with error:

> Error 1406. Could not write value InstallFolder to key
>   \"SOFTWARE\MySoftwareGroup\MySoftware"

You can see that the key contains the quotes. It should read:

> \SOFTWARE\MySoftwareGroup\MySoftware

If I remove the quotes from the define:

```
<?define registry_key_path=SOFTWARE\MySoftwareGroup\MySoftware ?>
```

the installer correctly parses the variable and finds the right registry key and writes to it.

Why are the quotes being included?

How would I quote the string value if it contained a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me with WiX v3.11.1.2318. Open your .msi in Orca to inspect the `Registry` table and see if the quotes exist there. If you can reproduce it in a small example .wixproj, please [open a bug](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried creating this inside a new project, and despite replicating the project as closely as I can to the original, I can't recreate the issue. Additionally, I now can't recreate the issue in my original project ... so either I'd done something daft, or a gremlin or restart has sorted it out. Thanks for your help however. Marked as the answer to close the question.